# rotate the fill function of matplotlib in a figure

Tags: python, matplotlib, scipy

I am trying to make a three joint plot. The frame of one of the plots is rotated by 90 degrees with respect to the other and perpendicular to the axis of the other. So I can make a histogram plot in this frame but when I use `kde` and generate data and use `fill` to overlay to the `hist` it won't rotate.

```
import pylab as plt
import seaborn as sns

from scipy.stats import gaussian_kde
import numpy as np
from astroML.plotting import hist

from mpl_toolkits.axes_grid1 import make_axes_locatable
sns.set_style("ticks")

axScatter = plt.subplot(111)

xmin, xmax = x.min(), x.max()
ymin, ymax = y.min(), y.max()

# Peform the kernel density estimate
xx, yy = np.mgrid[xmin:xmax:100j, ymin:ymax:100j]
positions = np.vstack([xx.ravel(), yy.ravel()])
values = np.vstack([x, y])
kernel = gaussian_kde(values)
f = np.reshape(kernel(positions).T, xx.shape)


axScatter.set_xlim(xmin, xmax)
axScatter.set_ylim(ymin, ymax)
# Contourf plot
cfset = axScatter.contourf(xx, yy, f, cmap='Blues')
## Or kernel density estimate plot instead of the contourf plot
#ax.imshow(np.rot90(f), cmap='Blues', extent=[xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax])
# Contour plot
cset = axScatter.contour(xx, yy, f, colors='k')
# Label plot
axScatter.scatter(x, y, marker='o', s=1, alpha=0.2, color='k')
axScatter.set_aspect('auto')

axScatter.set_xlabel(r'$X$')
axScatter.set_ylabel(r'$Y$')



# create new axes on the right and on the top of the current axes.
divider = make_axes_locatable(axScatter)

axHistx = divider.append_axes("top", size=1.2, pad=0.1, sharex=axScatter)
axHisty = divider.append_axes("right", size=1.2, pad=0.1, sharey=axScatter)

# the scatter plot:
# histograms
kde = gaussian_kde(x)
X_plot = np.linspace(xmin, xmax, 1000)
X_dens = kde.evaluate(X_plot)
axHistx.fill(X_plot, X_dens, fc='#AAAAFF',alpha=0.2)
hist(x, bins='knuth', ax=axHistx, color='black', histtype='step', normed=True)


kde = gaussian_kde(y)
Y_plot = np.linspace(ymin,ymax, 1000)
Y_dens = kde.evaluate(Y_plot)
axHisty.fill(Y_plot, Y_dens, fc='#AAAAFF' ,alpha=0.2)
hist(y, bins='knuth', ax=axHisty, color='black', histtype='step', normed=True, orientation='horizontal')
```

How can I rotate the fill function in right panel?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [`fill_betweenx`](http://matplotlib.org/api/axes_api.html#matplotlib.axes.Axes.fill_betweenx) function of the `axHisty` axes to do this:

```
axHisty.fill_betweenx(Y_plot, Y_dens, color='#AAAAFF' ,alpha=0.2)
```

Note the `fill_betweenx` doesn't take `fc` as a `kwarg`, but does take `color`.

I modified the [`scatter_hist.py`](http://matplotlib.org/examples/pylab_examples/scatter_hist.html) example from the matplotlib gallery to have histograms and fills in the same style as your plot, and used the `fill_betweenx` line above, to create this plot:

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot ! How did you hide ticks for the top and right panels?

Comment: I didn't - that happened automatically from the example I linked to. But: you can remove the labels with: `axHistx.set_xticklabels([])` and `axHisty.set_yticklabels([])`

Comment: I could hide the ticks using this command line :`for ty in axHistx.get_yticklabels():
        ty.set_visible(False)` but the ticks on top left of the top panel (`1e-14`) is still there. I don't know how to get rid of it. Do you have any suggestion?

Comment: This should do it: `axHistx.yaxis.get_offset_text().set_visible(False)`